# What should I do? error: Cannot find module 'ejs '

Tags: node.js, module, ejs

I have the same error as the title. I installed express and ejs, but the same error is still occurring. Somebody help me.

Here is my complete error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ejs '
Require stack:
- /Users/hoodie/Desktop/projects/node/login-lecture/node_modules/express/lib/view.js
- /Users/hoodie/Desktop/projects/node/login-lecture/node_modules/express/lib/application.js
- /Users/hoodie/Desktop/projects/node/login-lecture/node_modules/express/lib/express.js
- /Users/hoodie/Desktop/projects/node/login-lecture/node_modules/express/index.js
- /Users/hoodie/Desktop/projects/node/login-lecture/app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at new View (/Users/hoodie/Desktop/projects/node/login-lecture/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:81:14)
    at Function.render (/Users/hoodie/Desktop/projects/node/login-lecture/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:587:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/hoodie/Desktop/projects/node/login-lecture/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7)
    at /Users/hoodie/Desktop/projects/node/login-lecture/app.js:9:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/hoodie/Desktop/projects/node/login-lecture/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/hoodie/Desktop/projects/node/login-lecture/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKe6T.png)

My source code is also very simple:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.set("views", "./views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs ");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home/index");
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home/login");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("working");
});
```

Comment: `npm install ejs`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the empty space after `ejs`

From:

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs ");
```

To:

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```